# Get OperationContracts from DLL file using Assembly

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I open DLL files using `Assembly` class. Now I want to get methods that have `[OperationContract]` attribute. How to do that?

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(someDLLFilePath);
Type[] classes = assembly.GetTypes();
```

Comment: [Check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foo = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
          where type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ServiceContractAttribute>().Any()
          from method in type.GetMethods()
          where method.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<OperationContractAttribute>().Any()
          select method;
```

Comment: +1 You are assuming that the type has the `ServiceContractAttribute`, which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single instruction to do that, you have to iterate on methods and see if it has the attribute. You could something like this:

```
foreach (var type in classes)
{
  type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(false).Contains(typeof (OperationContract)));
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but `OperationContract` should be replaced by `OperationContractAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = assembly
    .DefinedTypes
    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods()
                            .Where(method => method
                                .GetCustomAttributes<OperationContractAttribute>()
                                .Count() > 0)
        );
```

Comment: returns IEnumerable<Type>()